# How to get added files in $_FILES with blueimp jQuery File Upload?

Tags: php, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm using the BlueImp jQuery File Upload Basic Plus UI.
I want to remove the default "Start upload" button and just submit the whole form with my own submit button.

But on submit I get an empty result with `var_dump($_FILES)`.

How do I get it to populate the `$_FILES` variable?

**Update:**

I can get the `$_FILES` values by setting this option: `replaceFileInput: false`. But it only contains values for the last added file. Anyway to get all added files instead?

Current options:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    autoUpload: false,
    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/.test(window.navigator.userAgent),
    maxFileSize: 5000000,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    replaceFileInput: false,
    singleFileUploads: false
});
```

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#singlefileuploads ?

Comment: Yup. Just tried and it still contain only the last added values of the last added file.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but did you solved the problem? I am getting crazy with this issue. I see in the javascript console log that the JS object is correct (it contains several files) but in PHP the $_FILES only contains one. Did you solved the problem?